# numpy: Computing mean and std over multiple non-consecutive axes (2nd attempt)

Tags: python, numpy

[An earlier version of this post got absolutely no response, so, in case this was due to a lack of clarity, I've reworked it, with additional explanations and code comments.]

I want to compute a mean and standard deviation over elements of a numpy *n*-dimensional array that do not correspond to a single axis (but rather to *k* > 1 *non-consecutive* axes), and get the results collected in a new (*n* - *k* + 1)-dimensional array.

> Does numpy include standard constructs to perform this operation efficiently?

The function `mu_sigma` copied below is my best attempt at solving this problem, but it has two glaring inefficiencies: 1) it requires making a copy of the original data; 2) it computes the mean twice (since the computation of the standard deviation requires computing the mean).

The `mu_sigma` function takes two arguments: `box` and `axes`.  `box` is an *n*-dimensional numpy array (aka "ndarray"), and `axes` is a *k*-tuple of integers, representing (not necessarily consecutive) dimensions of `box`.  The function returns a new (*n* - *k* + 1)-dimensional ndarray containing the mean and standard deviation computed over the "hyperslabs" of `box` represented by the *k* specified axes.

The code below also includes an example of `mu_sigma` in action.  In this example, the `box` argument is a 4 x 2 x 4 x 3 x 4 ndarray of floating-point numbers, and the `axes` argument is the tuple (1, 3).  (Hence, we have *n* == `len(box.shape)` == 5, and *k* == `len(axes)` == 2.)  The result (which here I'll call `outbox`) returned for this sample input is a 4 x 4 x 4 x 2 ndarray of floating point numbers.  For each triplet of indices *i*, *k*, *j* (where each index ranges over the set {0, 1, 2, 3}), the element `outbox[i, j, k, 0]` is the mean of the 6 elements specified by the numpy expression `box[i, 0:2, j, 0:3, k]`.  Similarly, `outbox[i, j, k, 1]` is the standard deviation of the same 6 elements.  This means that the first *n* - *k* == 3 dimensions of the result range over the same indices as do the *n* - *k* non-axes dimensions of the input ndarray `box`, which in this case are dimensions 0, 2 and 4.

The strategy used in `mu_sigma` is to

1. permute the dimensions (using the `transpose` method) so that the axes specified in the function's second argument are all put at the end; the remaining (non-axes) dimensions are left at the beginning (in their original ordering);
2. collapse the axes dimensions into one (by using the `reshape` method); the new "collapsed" dimension is now the last dimension of the reshaped ndarray;
3. compute an ndarray of the means using the last "collapsed" dimension as axis;
4. compute an ndarray of the standard deviations using the last "collapsed" dimension as axis;
5. return an ndarray obtained from concatenating the ndarrays produced in (3) and (4)

```
import numpy as np

def mu_sigma(box, axes):
    inshape = box.shape

    # determine the permutation needed to put all the dimensions given in axes
    # at the end (otherwise preserving the relative ordering of the dimensions)
    nonaxes = tuple([i for i in range(len(inshape)) if i not in set(axes)])

    # permute the dimensions
    permuted = box.transpose(nonaxes + axes)

    # determine the shape of the ndarray after permuting the dimensions and
    # collapsing the axes-dimensions; thanks to Bago for the "+ (-1,)"
    newshape = tuple(inshape[i] for i in nonaxes) + (-1,)

    # collapse the axes-dimensions
    # NB: the next line results in copying the input array
    reshaped = permuted.reshape(newshape)

    # determine the shape for the mean and std ndarrays, as required by
    # the subsequent call to np.concatenate (this reshaping is not necessary
    # if the available mean and std methods support the keepdims keyword;
    # instead, just set keepdims to True in both calls).
    outshape = newshape[:-1] + (1,)

    # compute the means and standard deviations
    mean = reshaped.mean(axis=-1).reshape(outshape)
    std = reshaped.std(axis=-1).reshape(outshape)

    # collect the results in a single ndarray, and return it
    return np.concatenate((mean, std), axis=-1)

inshape = 4, 2, 4, 3, 4
inbuf = np.array(map(float, range(np.product(inshape))))
inbox = np.ndarray(inshape, buffer=inbuf)
outbox = mu_sigma(inbox, tuple(range(len(inshape))[1::2]))

# "inline tests"
assert all(outbox[..., 1].ravel() ==
           [inbox[0, :, 0, :, 0].std()] * outbox[..., 1].size)
assert all(outbox[..., 0].ravel() == [float(4*(v + 3*w) + x)
                                      for v in [8*y - 1
                                                for y in [3*z + 1
                                                          for z in range(4)]]
                                      for w in range(4)
                                      for x in range(4)])
```

Comment: This approach seems like the right one to me. mean is so much faster than std I wouldn't worry about calculating the mean twice. And it's pretty common when using numpy/matlab type vectorization to make temporary data copies. It's the price we pay for the usability and speed of numpy, I wouldn't worry about it unless you're hitting some sort of memory limitations.
One small note about `newshape`, try `newshape = tuple(inshape[i] for i in nonaxes) + (-1,)`

Comment: @Bago: the trick with -1 as the last element is a shape tuple is great!  Thanks!

Comment: @kjo: By the way, you don't have to repost your question. According to [this Meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions), you can just edit it (with useful information on your progress / a better explanation) and it'll get bumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this got a little easier as of numpy 2.0.

http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/1234

Comment: That link is broken.